# Data residency of Google Vision within a Country

Tags: google-cloud-vision

This is regarding data security concern of an Australian Healthcare client.
We have integrated Google Vision for OCR for their text extraction requirement.

Client has a concern regarding their data being stored (temporarily) in the google cloud for text extraction. The data should not be sent outside Australia.

I understand that google has provision to choose the location of the bucket as Australia from the attached screenshot. Can you please help us understanding if this would answer the data residency concern of the client?

Appreciate your help and guidance in advance.

---

Ishan Shah

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WycDD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding cloud storage,

- The region specification does not mean that the data stored in the bucket will be available just within the chosen region. Choosing the region affects the availability of the resource from the region and etc, To see what else you can consider when choosing a region visit the link [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations).
- Data access in your cloud storage will depend on access control settings you provided for the bucket. You have an option for [fine grained and uniform access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control) for this.

In Vision OCR,

- I believe this documentation is a good reference to how Google stores data when using this resource. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage

Google ensures that you have control over your data and are committed to protect your data. See their privacy policy here: https://cloud.google.com/privacy

> We want to be clear about how we proactively protect your data and prioritize your privacy. We start from the fundamental premise that as a Google Cloud customer, you own your customer data. We implement stringent security measures to safeguard your customer data and provide you with tools and features to control it on your terms. We similarly secure any service data generated through providing the services; service data itself is critical to help ensure security and availability.

I hope these references are helpful, when you still have doubts you can always contact Google for such information: https://cloud.google.com/contact

Comment: Thanks, Nestor.
The concern here is the data should not be stored / processed by Google outside a Region (Australia).

I believe your answer refers to Data accessibility.

Comment: Understood,  if you are inquiring about where Google stores data internally I do not think they can disclose that information publicly, The closest information I can get you is there privacy page I included above. I would recommend though for contacting Sales for any doubts you have and possibly answer your question.